# library for representing 3D polyhedra

Tags: python, 3d, polygon

Are there any libraries that provide 3D polyhedra, and support calculating the intersection of two polyhedra?

If it makes a difference, the polyhedra I want to model do not have 'holes' in them.

The focus would be on correctness first and speed a close second!

Ideally this library would:

- have existing tidy python bindings
- be free-standing or have reasonable and small dependencies
- support calculating the outline of the polyhedron when view from any given angle

Comment: Did you find what you were looking for with CGAL? How are you computing the intersection of polyhedra? Thanks.

Comment: @Geoff sorry I have difficulty even recalling the project this was for; I think I ended up writing my own not-fast code from first-principles; but looking at it, CGAL seems a good choice for you to explore.

Comment: Thanks for the follow up. I'm working with the `Nef_polyhedron_3` class for now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[CGAL](http://www.cgal.org/) offers rather more than you're asking for, but does in particular include polyhedra and "boolean"-like operations on them (I'm not sure about "view from any angle" as a primitive, though -- as I recall it wasn't there when I last used it, but that was a while ago -- you may have to iterate projecting the hedges on the appropriate plane).

The Python bindings are [here](http://cgal-python.gforge.inria.fr/) and I believe the only "big" dependency is Boost Python (used for the bindings).