# Convex polyhedra intersection in Python

Tags: python, geometry, computational-geometry

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [library for representing 3D polyhedra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3151524/library-for-representing-3d-polyhedra)

**Is there a readily available Python library for testing if two convex polyhedra (3D) intersect?**

As input I have the coordinates, and if necessary, the facets that define the polyhedra. I've spent some time looking at the mathematics of [separating hyperplanes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperplane_separation_theorem), [Minkowski addition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_addition) and the [Gilbert–Johnson–Keerthi distance algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gilbert%E2%80%93Johnson%E2%80%93Keerthi_distance_algorithm) and I feel like I'm getting lost in the details. I'd rather not reinvent the wheel if possible and code my own. This is especially true if a robust library already exists. A minimal working example would be extremely helpful!

Comment: that could be a potentially expensive calculation but I think you would take each vertice on one and test if it lies inside of a grouping of any 3 vertices on the other one... It is alot cheaper to treat them as cubes,circles or triangles according to the the closest representation

Comment: Would doing some random sampling (i.e. uniformly across poly1 and checking for whether a point is in poly2, or close to poly2) be sufficient? *You should be able to get very high confidence in such a calculation.*

Comment: @hayden I was, in fact, using a random sampling previously. I am at the point where I need the exact answer - a false positive may cause a later computation to blow up.

Comment: The wording is not the same but I think this answers your question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3151524/422353

Comment: Don't vote down without giving reasons for it please!